# density plot of data from uniform distribution looking like normal distribution

Tags: r, distributions, data-visualization

I have generated random data from uniform distribution, `runif(25, -1, 1)`

I am trying to plot the density , so I used the plot function, `plot(density(runif(25, -1, 1)))`

I was expecting a uniform density like like this below

[image: Expected Uniform Distribution]

What I am seeing is like this below, which looks like a normal distribution,

[image: Actual Uniform Distribution]

Need help understanding where I am going wrong.

Comment: What does the density()-function do?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala - you've basically answered the question, Socratically; you may as well fill it in a little and post it as an answer!

Comment: In case these comments aren't clear, try `(function(x) sapply(c(1,0.1), function(a) plot(density(x, adjust=a))))(runif(25, -1, 1))`. This generates random data and plots their density twice: once with the default bandwidth and again with one-tenth the bandwidth.